# Deriving Loop Equations in a Circuit with 2 batteries?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

First time posting here, so please help with formatting.

I need help deriving loop equations for this becaue the 2 batteries/power supplies are throwing me off.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUoid.png

The only one I can think of so far is: (not sure if i'm right)

$$6 ~\rm V - 4 i_0 - i_3 = 0$$

($i_0$ is the one to the right of the $6 ~\rm V$ supply and $i_3$ is the one with the ammeter on it)

so the current in the 4 Ohm resistor is $1 ~\rm A$.

Really stuck on what else to do. Please help!

Comment: RE: "Really stuck on what else to do." Try writing an equation for the other loop. Your first equation is basically correct, but it would be more clear if you got the units right (include the 1 $\Omega$ factor in the third term, for exampel).

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you for your help! It's just I'm confused if the 2A current near the ammeter goes up or down (toward 6V supply or away), which is really inhibiting my ability to write another loop equation

Comment: Since you know the reading on the voltmeter, the ammeter is actually not telling you anything new, so just ignore it if you want to. (but if you must know, it's only consistent if the +2 A read on the ammeter is indicating current flowing in to the + terminal)

Comment: You need to label the current directions, too, or you are going to miss many + and - signs and get wrong results.  Solving circuits like this requires meticulous work with signs.

Comment: What is the resistance of the ampere meter? Usually it is quite low and then you can replace it by a short circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so the current in the 4 Ohm resistor is 1 A.

This conclusion is not correct.  Find the voltage across (and current through) the $4 \Omega$ resistor by writing a KVL equation counter-clockwise around the loop including the resistor, battery and voltmeter:

$$I_1 4\Omega -2V -6V = 0 \Rightarrow I_1 = \frac{2V + 6V}{4 \Omega} = 2A$$

Then, by KCL, we have:

$$I_2 = I_1 + 2A = 4A$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: You are right, and I was wrong. Thanks for posting the correct hint.